# Android app that identify an object

Tags: android, image-processing, image-recognition

Is there any possible way to develop and implement an app that will only show us text message/details on the camera screen:

1. When we are pointing our devices on that particular object.
2. When we have set the distance between the user and the object say 20 metres.

I know we can use image recognition to do this but I was wondering if there is any other feasible approach? Any suggestions would highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are not using image recognition, then how would you know what you're pointing the camera at?

Comment: As I said the data already been stored in DB. We use the camera function just for viewer finder to make sure that we pointing the right object and for accuracy purposed. We could just point the device to the object but I think using the camera as interactive much fun. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds a lot like Google Goggles. You take a picture, it gets scanned in the phone, and it tells you what the object is.

I think what you're asking though, is more like [this, though](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2135341/The-camera-prints-sees--taking-photo.html). This camera takes a picture of whatever it's looking at, and prints out what you're seeing in text. Maybe that can point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the input - well that's very good article but that is not exactly I meant. The camera on the device only use for viewer finder to get the accuracy of which object the user is pointing. It did not has the function to taking photo nor scan the object. 

I have seen the Google Goggles which almost similar concept but again those app able to use the camera to taking photos then scan isnt that I am looking for. The object that I am interested in here already stored in the DB. And I think using the data in the DB and user current location we might able to do this? Open to discussion.

Comment: I'm going to assume English isn't your native language, haha. No worries though, that was just hard to read through :]. I'm moderately sure what you want to do isn't feasible. More so, it would be so complicated that if you have to ask us what the name of the technology is, it would be VERY difficult to code. No disrespect meant, it's just that it's a complicated thing to wear out.

Not QUITE the same thing, but have you thought of RFID tags? Put a tag in whatever you want to be able to distinguish, then match some text with the RFID frequency, so when the freq is read you get the description.

Comment: Thanks again for the ideas Henry EQ IV, and sorry for the bad explanation due to English isn't my first language. 

So what you are saying was; if I'm not using the method of image processing / recognition then the chances to develop this app is not possible? 

I haven't heard of RFID but I have now after reading about it. Thanks for the info; using a 'chip' seems one of the solution. So if we using the chip to incoporate with the app; would that be possible?

Comment: I am still think... there must be a better way to implement 'this' app apart from using the 'tags' as I thought by storing all the data in the DB and knowing the user current location as well as able to distinguish the direction where the object is (Using the formule of tri) - it might be possible?

Comment: What I meant was that if you're asking for help as to where to start, it's going to be a long and difficult build for you. Completely do-able though. The RFID tag will have a certain radio frequency. I'm not sure if the Android phone will have the ability to read the frequency, but if you can find an attachment that does, it can match the frequency to something in your database to pull up information about it on the phone.

Comment: Okay, thanks - well the idea of the RFID is good but that isn't something I am consider at the moment. As I think if we know:

1. the user current location
2. the direction of the object.
3. the distance of the object.
4. the object stored in the DB
5. compass.

It seems quite feasible? Maybe someone could give some ideas how these all above (1-5) methods by combining them together. The particular object that the user interested in might be able to show on their device?

Comment: Just let me tell you... based on your skill level (at least what I can perceive), this is going to give you one hell of a hard time getting this together. Good luck though!